# ''Neither... nor '' / just ''nor'' / just''neither''

Tags: conjunctions

I can make this sentence in three different ways.

A)We ***neither*** got to see the castle ***nor*** did we see the cathedral.***[Neither .... nor]***

B)We didn't get to see the castle ***neither*** did we see the cathedral.***[just ''neither'']***

C)We didn't get to see the castle ***nor*** did we see the cathedral.***[just ''nor'']***

İs there any difference in nuance in the meaning between these 3 sentences or are they completely in the same meaning?

Comment: There's really no difference. The *not–neither/nor* versions tacitly imply an afterthought, something like *and also this*, while in the *neither–nor* version your mind is already made up; you know what you're about to say. The first example is very textbook-like and thus perhaps a bit more formal. There are other versions as well, such as *We didn't see the castle, and we didn't see the cathedral either.* The basic meaning is the same, and I wouldn't worry about this at all. Further (this might just be my opinion as a non-native speaker) the 2nd example would sound better with *and neither*.

Comment: @userr2684291  As a native English speaker, I agree with your comment.  In a normal English conversation, I would expect to hear, "We didn't get to see the castle or the cathedral."

Answer (score 1):

None of these sentences sound right to me as a native (US) English speaker. That is because the usual phrase construction is

> Neither [noun] nor [noun]

So you could say something like

> We saw neither the castle nor the cathedral.

Or you could say

> We didn't get to see either the castle or the cathedral.

Notice that when you use 'didn't' you already have a negative, and so using didn't with neither/nor is incorrect because you're using a double negative.

Neither/nor can be thought of as the opposite of either/or or both/and.